# Twilio action (on gather user input via dtmf) using Flask

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to grab user input using `<Gather>` via `dtmf` which I successfully to do, in `twilio` itself

Now I was trying to use `Flask`. Everything is working fine expect `action` attribute in `<Gather>`. 
suppose I provide the `action` path to `https://gather-user-input.twil.io/voice-function` which works properly but I want to execute `voice_function.js` when `user` hits any button when called made.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from twilio.rest import Client
from config import ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN, TWILIO_NUMBER

client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    with open('voice.xml', 'r') as file:
        twiml_content = file.read()

    call = client.calls.create(
        to='+91xxxxxxxxxx',
        from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
        twiml=twiml_content
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**voice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Message From XYZ company</Say>
    <Gather numDigits="1" action="voice_function">
        <Say>For Insurance Press 1, Press any key to end this call.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

**voice_function.js**

```
// this function is similar to the function which is defined in twilio Service
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  console.log("this is working", `User Pressed ${event.Digits}`);

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();


  const userChoice = event.Digits;
  let message = "Thanks for giving your time";

  if (userChoice === "1") {
    message = "Thats Great! Glad we will never let you down";
  }

  twiml.say(message);
  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking how to terminate the call?

Comment: @IObert I am trying to make a call to a user and grab a input from them and trying to log the result inside my flask application

Comment: And what is not working? Are you getting no response at all, or only one saying "Thanks for giving your time" without "Thats Great! Glad we will never let you down"?

And just to confirm, you also see "this is working User Pressed 1" in the logs?


Please add all these details in the original question

Comment: @IObert (detail )when i run my `flask` app, & `ngrok` port `5000`, then visit to home page `call` is been made to my `number` by `twilio`. `Bot` reads out the `message` (voice.xml) then i provide input by hitting a `number`
where `Bot` say `we are sorry and application error occured..` 
I did try many things in my (voice.xml) file for example `action='https://19cc-122-168-217-211.ngrok-free.app/voice` or `action=http://127.0.0.1:5000/voice` or `action=some_js_file.js`

Comment: This probably means your webhook URL is incorrect or the webhook crashes. I recommend checking the error log <https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools>. Also, I don't understand why you have a flask server and then use a JS-based webhook that is hosted on Functions. Wouldn't it be easier to host the webhook also on your flask server?

Comment: @IObert thanks for your time, `issue` is been resolved I wasn't configuring `ngrok` properly